# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm running the following SQL block:

```
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE table_name (id INT NOT NULL)';
END;
```

And getting:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod...
```

I'm confused because this runs fine in Oracle SQL Developer, but when I execute it with the Oracle JDBC driver, it throws this error.

Comment: Are you trying to run stored procedure by embedding it in Java program? Shouldn't stored procedures stay on DB server and call them using CallableStatments?

Comment: It's part of the DB upgrade process we use, I can't change the underlying design.

Comment: Tried that, and from what I've read in other similar problems, it's best to leave it out.

Comment: Please show the Java code that calls this table creation code through JDBC.

Comment: @IanSellar semicolon is not required inside quotes for Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the way that the Oracle driver was parsing the SQL string.  Taking out the newlines fixed it.